# Select statement stops working when wrapped in view [Oracle]

Tags: oracle

I have a select statement in a stored procedure that I'd like to pull out and put into a view. The select statement pulls from dba_tables, dba_tab_partitions, and dba_tab_subpartitions.

If I run the statement on its own, it works fine. If I wrap it in a create view statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "MYSCHEMA"."V_XWMS_TEST"
(
"OWNER"
,"SEGMENT_NAME"
,"PARTITION_NAME"
,"SEGMENT_TYPE"
,"TABLESPACE_NAME"
)
AS
SELECT "OWNER"
,"SEGMENT_NAME"
,"PARTITION_NAME"
,"SEGMENT_TYPE"
,"TABLESPACE_NAME"
FROM
[Original query]
```

then depending on which user I'm logged in as, I get either ORA-01031: insufficient privileges or ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Again, with both users I can create views and I can run this select statement, but I can't run the select statement in the context of creating a view.

Comment: Does your user have access to read from all tables included in that view?

Comment: Yes - both users can run the select statement on its own and get the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by the difference between the system privilege `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` and the role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`.

On the surface they do the same thing by granting users access to the data dictionary.  Either one of them would enable a user to run a query against tables like `DBA_TABLES`.

The difference is that roles are *not* enabled when creating objects with definer's rights, and views are always definer's rights.  So to make the view work the user will need the system privilege `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`, or a similar direct grant on individual objects.

Comment: Granting select any dictionary allowed me to create the view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01031: insufficient privileges or ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

This error means that the new table from which the view is created doesn't have synonyms and grants created to be accessed by the schema in which the view is created.